# Get whole query from the URL

Tags: javascript, hash, prototypejs

i have a problem to get the whole query from the url using the toQueryParams function from the protoypejs framework e.G.:

```
var a = "http://anypage.com?a=lol&b=lal&c=laoa?&d=fehw#lalalalalSomeAnchor";

a.toQueryParams();

>> {d: 'fehw'}

what i want to get:

>> {a: 'lol', b: 'lal', c: 'loaa?', d: 'fehw'}
```

i know that url is invalid but i want to preprocess that url to escape its values before i sent it to the server.

I tried to change the functions regular expression to match only the chars between the first ? and the lastest #, i have already one expression /(\?.*#)/ which would work for me but i even want to exclude the ? and #, i hope someone of you can help me out :)

btw. that page below is awsome to build regexp in realtime :P
http://regexpal.com/

**Update**: thanks to DaveRandom :)
for those who wants to fix that directly in the framwork replace following line with:

```
L625: var match = this.strip().match(/\?([^#]*)/); // (/([^?#]*)(#.*)?$/); default
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this... `/\?([^#]*)/`?

You shouldn't need to worry about matching up to the 'last' `#` because the anchor starts at the first `#`, therefore even if there is more than one `#` in the string, anything after the first occurence is not part of the query string.

Comment: I'm not sure but it does not seem to work either: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/rWE62/. Prototype seems to read everything after the last `?`.

Comment: You have to URL Encode your variables. Use encodeURIComponent("value"); before adding it to your url.

Comment: The above works for me (gives me `?a=lol&b=lal&c=laoa?&d=fehw` which is what is required, isn't it?), with the caveat that the string still has the first `?` on it, which I believe is impossible to avoid with this operation (although I could be wrong, someone please correct me if they know otherwise). You can always `substr()` the first `?` off.

Comment: @Marc, i know but the problem is my function receives already that "fu**** up" url and i need to exploid that escape its values and put it back to a valid url... thats why i need that function to be able to support more ?'s

Comment: @tetra, What you can do is split your url by the first ?, then split the second part [basically the variables and values], split it by the = (equals character).. encode all values and join everything together to complete your properly encodes url.

Answer (score 0):

User `/\?([^#]*)/` as DaveRandom answered, and remember to URL Encode your variables. Use `encodeURIComponent("value");` before adding it to your url. ..Can't have two `?` in your url.

Comment: the second match doesnt include the ? and #

Answer (score 0):

Here, this works.... I just took everything between the first `?` and the last `#`, concatenated and ran toQueryParams on it. Maybe this is good enough?

http://jsfiddle.net/cQYV7/1/

**edit** Also replaced all `?&` with `?` so all parameters are matched...

Comment: nope i dont want to loose any data, replace is bad in my case